# Is there any possibility to check the previous and next element in foreach loop?

Tags: java

in java using for each how to check previous and next elements.
Is there any possibility to check previous and next element in for each loop

Comment: sure. Post your code

Comment: it is better to opt for old-school `for loop` with index

Comment: You can store the previous element in a variable. But the next element will only be known at the next iteration. Why not use a standard for loop?

Comment: You can also use listIterator becuase it has both next and previous method.

Comment: if you like any answer you can surely upvote it.. but please don't downvote an answer unless it's totally wrong. Thank you :) Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

No.

The "for each" construct uses `Iterator` underneath, which only has a `next()` and `hasNext()` functions. No way to get `previous()`.

`Lists` have a `ListIterator` which does allow looking at the previous element, but "for each" doesn't know how to use it. The only solution is therefore to remember the previous element in a separate variable, or just use a simple counting loop like this: `for(int i=0;i< foo.length();i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using "for each" only has next() and hasNext() methods, so it doesn't provides methods for reverse traversing or extracting elements.

Considering you have a ArrayList of Strings, You can use `java.util.ListIterator` which provides methods such as `hasPrevious()` and `previous()`

Below is the sample of how it can be used . 
** Read the comments in side of code as it contains important details for using these methods.**

```
        ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

        ListIterator<String> myListIterator = mylist.listIterator();

        myListIterator.hasNext(); // Returns: true if list has next element
        myListIterator.next(); // Returns: next element , Throws:NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no next element
        myListIterator.hasPrevious(); // Returns: true if list has previous element
        myListIterator.previous(); //Returns: the previous element in the list , Throws: NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no previous element
```

Hope this helps.

PS : You should have posted the code which you have done so far, 
posting question on stackoverflow which does not contain anything to show your effort is really BAD.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the purpose of this?

Instead of a `foreach` you should probably use a `for` loop and indexing

```
for(int i=0;i<lenght;i++) {
    list[i-1].dostuff //previous
    list[i].dostuff //current
    list[i+1].dostuff //next item
}
```

and don't forget to check if the next item and previous exists.

Comment: You don't check if the elements you're about to retrieve exist (I know you mention checking if the next item exists, but still) and you don't use braces for the for loop.

Comment: Your answer would cause an array out of bounds on the first go through and is syntactically wrong

Comment: yes I know it is not perfect code, I'm just visualizing how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

> Some of the limitations of for Each loop.Can read the whole article
>   for clear overview
>   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-each-loop-in-java/

Also,This can be one way:

```
    public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr={"a","b"};
    String next="";
    String current="";
    String prev="";

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

        //previousElement
        if(i>0){ 
            prev=arr[i-1] ;
            System.out.println("previous: "+prev);
       }else{
           prev="none";
          System.out.println("previous: "+prev);
               }

         //currentElement      
        current=arr[i];
       System.out.println(" current: "+current);

       //nextElement
      if(i<arr.length-1){
          next=arr[i+1];
          System.out.println(" next: "+next);
              }else{
                  next="none";
                  System.out.println(" next: "+next);
                              }
                }
  }
}
```

Attaching the output also:  [image]

**P.S. can check the code on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler**

Comment: What if sometimes `String[] arr={"a","b"};`

Comment: @manikantgautam updated the solution. If satisfied kindly accept it